# PHP/HTML feedback form: How to get the URL of the current page?

Tags: php, html, forms, webforms

I am working on creating a simple feedback form using HTML and PHP. The form and script are working, and I am receiving the submitted emails, except for one issue:
=> I want the feedback form to send the URL of the page where the feedback form was used and receive it in my email. I would like to know which page the user is talking about. For example, if a user clicked the feedback button and opened the feedback form (modal) on `http://example.com/features` page, I want the URL of that page (`http://example.com/features`) in my email along with the feedback message.

Here are my HTML and PHP:

HTML Form:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div id="modal-box" class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2>Some Heading?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
         <!--The submitt button in the form redirects action to the PHP script for message submission -->
        <form action="http://example.com/mailer.php" role="form" name="feedbackForm" id="feedback_docs"  method="post" >
           <textarea id="comments" type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Please write your comments about this topic here." style="height:200px"></textarea>
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
</div>      
<div id="myBtn">
    <button id="popup" class="feedback-button">FEEDBACK</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 $comments = $_POST['comments'];
 $to = 'feedback@example.com';
 $subject = 'Feedback received from website';
 $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
 $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
 $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
 $body = "Message: \r\r $comments";
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $url, $body)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

If you look at the PHP script, I have tried adding the follwing:

`$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];`

and I also tried :

`$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`,

but neither worked.

I am just learning PHP and scripting, so I have probably made some mistakes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This doesn't look like the PHP is doing any interaction work. How do you get the information back using AJAX / JavaScript? Please post that code. You need to do something in the `success` event.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question correctly. Now I have answered it well.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever file the user is in, the request finally goes to the same PHP file. So, you need to find the referrer. But it's unreliable in the PHP side. Instead, what you do is to use hidden inputs and pass that as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fromPage" value="feedbackForm" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="https://www.example.com/feedback.html" />
```

And then capture them in your `POST` data and send it to your email.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Soolie. We have hundreds of pages. What I have done is added the form to the master page. I would probably need to add some sort of a variable that will automatically send the URL of the specific page in my email, without writing the full URL as a value? So, if I use hidden inputs in the form, how would I capture that in the PHP?

Comment: Ahhh... Okay... :) You can dynamically create the `<input type="hidden" name="url" value="https://www.example.com/feedback.html" />` using `<input type="hidden" name="url" value="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are using some parts incorrectly.
The proper two are

```
 $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Forbs. I tried adding your suggestion, but I didn't receive the email, looks like it was successfully submitted, though.

Comment: If you aren't getting the email, that's a completely different question....you have to see if your mail server is setup properly and doesn't have a firewall, and allows outgoing...etc  `echo` out $url to see if that is setup properly

Comment: We have the server configured properly. I was getting that email, but it stopped after adding: `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`. I am still checking. I will update my post shortly. Thank you!

Comment: ah...then it's in your mail command, I thought it looked funny.   change `mail ($to, $subject, $url, $body)` to `mail ($to, $subject, $url. $body)` note the period after `$url`...I was wondering how the body could be a 4th parameter

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Forbs. Yes, it worked, but the URL I received was the PHP page `http://example.com/mailer.php`. I will try changing few things and see if it works. I am getting a URL in my email at least, that's a start for sure :)

Comment: To explain myself better: we have hundreds of pages and what I have done is added the form with a button to the master page. The button appears on each page throughout the site. If a user gives feedback about, say `http://example.com/feature` page, the user clicks the button which triggers a modal to open. When the feedback is submitted, I would like the `http://example.com/feature` URL to be submitted and not the `http://example.com/mailer.php`.

Comment: I changed the `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` and it worked. Yippie! Thanks a lot, Forbs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question. The answer that Forbs provided was very useful.

I changed the `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

The solution was pretty simple, my lack of experience in PHP made it challenging for me!